# uniform convergence of $f(\theta)=\theta, \theta \in [-\pi, \pi]$

Tags: fourier-series, uniform-convergence

I am mostly guessing using the theorem that because $f$ is Lipschitz continuous with $L= 2\pi$, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}\sin{n \theta}}{n}$ converges uniformly to $f$.
Is this start on the right track towards proving the uniform convergence on the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$?

Comment: is $f (x) = 0$ for all $x$?

Comment: Not specified, the question specifically asked to calculate the Fourier series of $f(\theta)=\theta$ for $-\pi < \theta \leq \pi$, which I hope I founded correctly, but then I do not know how to prove uniform convergence

Comment: $\frac{(-1)^{n+1}\sin{n \theta}}{n}$ converges to constant function $0$, maybe you mean $\sum\frac{(-1)^{n+1}\sin{n \theta}}{n}$?

Comment: Yes, apologies for my ignorant typing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When considering the uniform convergence of Fourier series, one must take into account the continuity of the periodic extension of $f$. This is because if a Fourier series converges uniformly on $[-\pi,\pi)$, then (by periodicity) it converges uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$; hence its sum is a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$.

Given that $f(\theta)=\theta$  on $(-\pi,\pi)$, it is clear that the periodic extension is discontinuous at $\pi$: the limit from the left is $\pi$, the limit from the right is $-\pi$. (It may help to sketch the periodic extension.) Thus the Fourier series **does not** converge uniformly.